# How to update a sql record text, by replacing a string for various text?

Tags: sql

I have to update a table record where I am replacing some  old email ids with a new id.

I am at the moment doing replace like

```
replace(replace(replace( column, 'abd@xyz.com', 'new@email.com),'old@re.com', 'new@email.com'),'asda@sdfsd.f', 'new@email.com')
```

Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag out help.  Also, what is the issue with your code?

Comment: Does the column really contains mutliple emails?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why a column would contain an email *and* other information.  So perhaps this does what you want:

```
update t
    set column = 'new@email.com'
    where column in ('abd@xyz.com', 'old@re.com', 'asda@sdfsd.f');
```

If the column contains additional information, I would recommend that you fix your data model rather than trying to make a broken data model work.

Comment: well it is indeed a legacy code, which can't be get rid of at the moment. And yes Column does have multiple email id  can't just replace all of it.